# How can I change author base in Wordpress and view the profile?

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a Wordpress site to review books and I think I am in some kind of trouble.

The thing is that I created a custom post type (authors) that is, the author of a certain book. Now I am trying to create user profile system and it looks like Wordpress already uses (author) base for its inherent users.

I tried to change the base to `user`, it worked but when I go to a user's front end like e.g: `http://localhost/wordpress/user/root/` I get redirected to the homepage.

How can I fix this problem? I want the two types to be separated and I be able to view users' profiles on my front end again.

Code

```
//Authors Custom Post Type
function author_custom_type() {
    $args = [
        'labels'    =>  ['name' => 'Authors', 'singular_name' => 'Authors'],
        'hierarchical'  => false,
        'public'    =>  true,
        'has_archive'   => 'authors',
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-edit',
        'supports'   =>  ['title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'custom-fields',],
        'rewrite'   =>  ['slug' =>  'author'],
    ];
    register_post_type('authors',
        $args
    );
}
add_action('init', 'author_custom_type');
```

```
//Changing site users' base from "/author" to `/user`
function wpa_82004() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->author_base = 'user';
}
add_action('init','wpa_82004');
```

Comment: Why are you messing with the `author_base` value? That is WordPress’ author, not your own custom post type. If you want a different URL base for your own custom post type - well then change `'rewrite'   =>  ['slug' =>  'author']` accordingly.

Comment: @CBroe The problem is that the site is up and indexed and it hard for me to change the base slug of the book author.

Comment: Just modifying a property of `$wp_rewrite` alone is likely not enough, you probably have to call the `flush_rules` method afterwards as well.